# Magento 1 (1.9.2.1) image uploader not working after patch 8788

Tags: patches, image-upload, ce-1.9.2.1, uploader

i've been patching a M 1.9.2.1 installation with the security patch 8788 and
since then the image uploader in the *catalog/product* page is not working anymore

THE PROBLEM

*browse* and *upload* buttons **DO** show up but when i select an image from my filesystem and upload it, i can't see the image preview in the images table

[image]
   .

WHAT HAPPENS

i can confirm the file is being uploaded under *media/tmp/catalog/product* but it doesn't show in the admin
as a result if i save the product, obviously, the image doesn't save and is not moved to the regular *media/catalog* folder

WHAT I TRIED

i have already been cleaning caches, reindexing, changing to the default theme, checking for the 
**lib/uploader/flow.min.js + fusty-flow.js + fusty-flow-factory.js + instance.js** 
files to be used instead of the swf flash files, so i also checked the obsolete flash component wasn't used anymore
...but nothing

i tried disabling all custom modules with no effect

file permissions under **lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php** at line 219 are already 0666 and 0777 at line 541

WHAT I NOTICED

is that in a M 1.9.2.2 patched installation, where the js uploader regularly works, the buttons show up on the right side, while here they show up on the left and the layout seems to be a little messed up

yesterday i started debugging  the js but im not very skilled on that...any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: SOLVED: this was due to an "unclean" application of the 8788 patch; i compared some files with another Magento installation with the patch working and found that some changes did not apply, so i manually applied them. Be careful if you use git for deploying patch applications through multiple environments

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but any idea what changes you had to apply manually ? I am having the exact same issue on a couple of sites and it is driving me nutty.

Comment: eventually got it working myself.   Applying the 8778v2 patch after the 6285v2 worked.